# HttpClient Call to WebApi Service on IIS 7.5 - 404 Not Found

Tags: c#, .net, iis, asp.net-web-api

I am new to WebApi and we have a requirement to create\maintain a token issuing web service. A colleague of mine provided his solution (beta) which he has allowed me to use. If I run the web service from my dev environment (VS 2012) I am able to query it and get the token back from a web browser (Chrome). I then wrote a test app to use HttpClient to query the service and get the token. This works fine from the service hosted in my dev environment but if I try to query it when hosted in IIS using my little test app I get a '404 Not Found' exception. But what is puzzling me is if I connect to the web service hosted in IIS from chrome it works?

My controller method is as follows:

```
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult GetToken(string username, string password, string realm)
{            
    return Json("TOKEN-STRING");
}
```

And my config:

```
<system.webServer>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />    
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
  <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" />
</modules>
<handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
  <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,PUT,DELETE,DEBUG" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,PUT,DELETE,DEBUG" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
</handlers>
```

I have set my application pool to 'Integrated' within IIS.

My logic says to me that if I am able to retrieve the token from Chrome but not from my app, then there should be nothing wrong with IIS but rather a config\setting\programming error in my app.

Here is the little method I wrote to get the token:

```
async private void GetToken()
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost/TokenServer/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        var response = client.GetAsync("/api/TokenServer/GetToken/name/password/realm").Result;
        string result =  await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            //Error handling
            return;
        }

        //Extract token from response
        JavaScriptSerializer json_serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        Token = DeserializeJsonToken(result);
    }
```

I have read and tried many suggestions but none seem to work for me. I have been stuck with this for two days now and the deadline is creeping :)

Tx

Comment: can you share how your web api routes configuration looks like?

Comment: `config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "TokenServerController",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{username}/{password}/{realm}",
            defaults: new { password = RouteParameter.Optional, realm = RouteParameter.Optional });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is with the Url where you have a leading `/` which causes the `TokenServer` part of the baseaddress Url to be not considered. So modify the call like the following:

```
client.GetAsync("api/TokenServer/GetToken/name/password/realm").Result;
```

A tip: Tools like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) can be of great use in situations like these. It helps in diagnosing the raw requests that are sent to the service.

Comment: Eish, I am very embarrassed to admit this but that was the problem. 2 days wasted thanks to a '/'. Thanks so much for your help!!!

Comment: Oh, and the fiddler tip.